# How can I change the dropdownlist's options?

Tags: drop-down-menu

I'm a newbie in asp.net so I'm hoping you could give me some help on my dropdownlist bound to a table.

Here's the scenario:

I have a table Account with fields UserId, UserName and Type. The Type field contains 3 items: 'S', 'A', and 'U'. Each user has his own Type. I have a dropdownlist named 'ddlType' which is already

bound on the Account table. However, I want the options of the dropdownlist to be displayed as 'Stakeholder', 'Approver', and 'User' instead of displaying letters/initials only. Since I do not prefer making any changes in the database, how can I change those options through code behind?

Here's my code:

public void BindControls(int selectedUserId)
{
    DataTable dtAccount = null;

```
try
{
    dtAccount = LogBAL.GetAccountDetails(selectedUserId);

    if (dtAccount.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        lblUserId.Text = dtAccount.Rows[0]["UserId"].ToString();
        txtUserName.Text = dtAccount.Rows[0]["UserName"].ToString();
        ddlType.SelectedValue = dtAccount.Rows[0]["Type"].ToString();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
finally
{
    dtAccount.Dispose();
}
```

}

Any help from you guys will be appreciated. Thanks in advanced! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can bind Dropdownlist in codebehind.

Get your data "Type" into array. Make array two dimentional and assign values to it.

After having data your array will looks like this,
    string[,] Types = { { "Stakeholder", "S" }, { "Approver", "A" }, { "User", "U" } };

Now assign values to Dropdown,
    int rows = Types.GetUpperBound(0);
    int columns = Types.GetUpperBound(1);
    ddlType.Items.Clear();
    for (int currentRow = 0; currentRow <= rows; currentRow++)
    {
        ListItem li = new ListItem();
        for (int currentColumn = 0; currentColumn <= columns; currentColumn++)
        {
               if (currentColumn == 0)
               {
                   li.Text = Types[currentRow, currentColumn];
               }
               else
               {
                   li.Value = Types[currentRow, currentColumn];
               }
         }
         ddlType.Items.Add(li);
    }

I haven't tested it but hopefully it will work.